# Importing data in a .dat file as a list of pairs

Tags: import

I have a .dat file with two columns (one for x axis and one for y axis). is it possible to import the file in order to make a list plot out of it, or do I have to format it into list format to plot it with Mathematica.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html

Comment: The import format you need to use is "Table", although if the file extension is ".dat" then that is implied.  All you need is  `ListPlot @ Import @ "myfile.dat"`

Comment: For others who may encounter this question, `.dat` is by no means a standard file format extension.  Mathematica by default takes `.dat` to mean `Table` format which is correct for this example.  The extension `.dat` really is so generic it could be about anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Data = Import["C:\\tcdata\\myfile.dat", "Table"][[All, {1, 2}]]

ListPlot[Data]
```